# How do I get a non-functioning hp 8710 office jet printer functioning again?

Tags: printing, hp

I installed all the Linux drivers from [123.hp.com](https://123.hp.com) and had my printer running just fine.  My OS is Ubuntu 16.04.

Then I did an 16.04 upgrade and the printer stopped and will not print.  I've unplugged, rebooted, deleted printer and tried to re-download drivers nothing works.  I've posted questions and have spent a frustrating week.

I would like to upgrade to Ubuntu 17.04 and start over but I don't know how to get the release.  It has been announced but I don't see it offered.

Comment: Is your question about how to upgrade to 17.04, or how to troubleshoot your printer?

Comment: I have a laptop that runs ubuntu 15.04.  My hp 8710 printer installs and works just fine there.  I looked into upgrading to 17.04 but decided not since it will not be supported past Jan 2018.  I will wait for additional upgrades to 16.04 and hope the it will let me reinstall my printer.

Answer (score 1):

I too have an HP printer. If I recall correctly, I had a similar problem, which I was able to diagnose and solve using HP's own diagnostic software. if you have utilities such as hp-check, you have hplip installed. If not, install hplip.

See http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html

Comment: This is what I got when I went to the following web site.
http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install_wizard/index.html

You have selected Ubuntu 16.04 using the HP Officejet Pro 8710 All-in-one Printer.

Ubuntu 16.04 supplies HPLIP 3.15.2 by default, which does not support your printer.

You must ensure latest HPLIP version (recommemded), or at least HPLIP 3.16.5 in order to use your printer with Ubuntu 16.04.

I tried to get the latest HPLIP 3.17.... but it failed.  You have pointed me to the solution but I don't know how to implement it.  Thanks.

Comment: Re-installed  HPLIP-3.15.2.run and reconfigured my printer via 123.hp..com  now every thing is back to normal.  My problem is solved.   Apparently ubuntu 16.04 has default version of HPLIP-3.16.6.run attached to it that is missing alot of printer configurations.